# question on complete vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

Could any one help me to solve these two problems on vector fields

1. Any $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ vector field on a compact manifold is complete.
2. Is every vector field on $\mathbb{R}$ complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st is true, not the 2nd. The flow associated to $\dot{x}=x^2$ is given by $\phi_t(x)=x/(1-tx)$, and obviously does not exist for every $t$.

Comment: could you explain me the first one?

Answer (score 3):

For the first, use the neighbourhood definition of compactness and do a proof by contradiction. The second is not true and you only have to find a suitable counter example.

Comment: could you explain me the first one?